# How can I convert an 'on click' button for history.back into pure JavaScript in template.js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this inline code on blog articles to take a user back to the previous page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Back</button>
```

How do I convert it to pure JavaScript to remove the inline 'onclick' and put the code into my template.js instead?

I presume the html would change to something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
```

And the JavaScript would be something along the lines of the following, but I'm missing a crucial part:

```
if (document.querySelector(".back")) {
  // there will only ever be one instance of the class "back"
  let backButton = document.querySelector(".back");
  backButton.onclick = function handleClick() {
  // what goes here?
  }
}
```

Am I along the right lines, or is there more to it that that?
TIA

Comment: Just add: {history.back();}

Comment: A side note about one subtle thing that may trip you up: at the time that your JavaScript executes (probably in the `<head>`) the `<button>` might not exist yet! In that case, the event handler won't be added. You can wait for the document to be done loading (but before images are loaded) with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* put your code here */ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write event listener for it too.

like this :

```
document.querySelector(".back").addEventListener('click',()=>{
  history.back()
})
```

Comment: Thanks @AliSattarzadeh. Almost the same as my accepted answer above.

Comment: your welcome, yes but I answered first @Gillian

Comment: My apologies, but when I came back to see the answers to this question your answer appeared second after the other. Mind you, the use of the optional chaining from mplungjan gave him an extra point. But I've accepted your answer, too.

Comment: thanks, that's really nice of you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using simple syntax:

```js
const backButton = document.querySelector(".back"); 
if (backButton) backButton.addEventListener("click", () => history.back());
```

alternatively use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
document.querySelector(".back")?.addEventListener("click", () => history.back());
```

As noted in a comment: If the script you execute is present before the button exists in the page, you need to wrap in a load event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector(".back")?.addEventListener("click", () => history.back());
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. The first code didn't work for me, but the second one did. My template.js is deferred, so I shouldn't have to use the "DomContentLoaded" code. I do have to use ```if (document.querySelector(".back"))``` otherwise I get a 'null' error on pages where the "back" class doesn't exist.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".back")?.addEventListener("click", () => history.back());` does that. It only adds the listener if the button exists

Comment: Is that using the ? symbol. That would save a lot of code in my template.js. (I really must sort myself out with a JavaScript course.)

Comment: `?.`  [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)